# ECSlidingViewController2 - hidden menu tappable with VoiceOver on

Tags: ios, uiaccessibility, ecslidingviewcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller-2

When using ECSlidingViewController2, How can we prevent the under left menu from being tapped with VoiceOver on and the menu is under the top view?  Try the BasicMenu example.  When on the Home view, you can tap the options on the menu underneath.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the voice over to read it, then make it inaccessible. Set the `isAccessibleElement` to `NO`.

This is a master switch for whether the element is accessible or not. `UIViews` and any custom direct subclasses of it are not accessible by default, whereas `UIControls` are. Elements which are not marked as accessible will be ignored by `VoiceOver`, and will be skipped when the user is navigating between accessible elements.

```
- (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement {
//if this is YES, VoiceOver won't continue to look for accessibility elements in this view's subviews
return NO;
}
```

Also you can set this to any UIView in your app.

Comment: I experimented with that, and it did not work.  I tried to even turn it off all the time to prove that it was working and couldn't get it to turn off.  Is there some timing issue where I was setting that at the wrong time?  Any other restrictions?  We have a underLeft table that represents our menu.  We want those cells to be accessible when the left menu is truly visible when the top view is anchored right.